# Concat all column values in sql

Tags: sql, concatenation

How to concat all column values from differenct rows returned from a sql query into one value? This is an example:

a query returns:

```
FOO
------
RES1

RES2

RES3
```

now I want to have a result like the following one:

```
FOOCONCAT
-----
RES1RES2RES3
```

Are there any ways to do this in sql?

Comment: Which server are you using? I doubt there's a generic SQL way to do it but there are certainly implementation specific methods.

Comment: I'm using Oracle. I'm astonished that there is no easy way to do this in oracle.

Answer (score 52):

In `SQL Server`:

```
SELECT  col1 AS [text()]
FROM    foo
FOR XML PATH ('')
```

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(col1 SEPARATOR '')
FROM    foo
```

In `PostgreSQL`:

```
SELECT  array_to_string
        (
        ARRAY
        (
        SELECT  col1
        FROM    foo
        ), ''
        )
```

In `Oracle`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) AS rn
        FROM    foo
        MODEL
        DIMENSION BY
                (rn)
        MEASURES
                (col1, col1 AS group_concat, 0 AS mark)
        RULES UPDATE (
                group_concat[rn > 1] =  group_concat[CV() - 1] || col1[CV()],
                mark[ANY] = PRESENTV(mark[CV() + 1], 0, 1)
                )
        )
WHERE   mark = 1
```

Comment: looks like a solution, but how would this look like in oracle?

Comment: That's a cool trick in SQL Server, I would just change the select to: SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(col1, '<col1>', ''), '</col1>', '')

Comment: @Quassnoi - I get "Column name 'Text()' contains an invalid XML identifier as required by FOR XML; '('(0x0028) is the first character at fault." on SQL Server 2005

Comment: Oh, [text()] is case-sensitive, I was trying [Text()].

Comment: Here is an alternate SQL Server approach: 
DECLARE @c AS VARCHAR(4000);
SET @c= '';
SELECT @ c= @c + col1 FROM Foo
select @c;

Comment: damn, why does it look so hard in oracle?

Comment: @dotjoe: group concatenation is not a classical set-based operation and was not available in any RDBMS until recently. Every solution you see (except MySQL) is a trick of some kind.

Comment: Does that mean oracle has little interest in going against the "set"?

Comment: @dotjoe: MODEL clause is Oracle's attempt to extend SQL beyond relational algebra a little.

Answer (score 9):

Quassnoi's Oracle solution is quite impressive, but I [found](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/code/tips2006/101606.html) [simpler](http://www.lazydba.com/oracle/0__111645.html) ones using SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH() rather than the MODEL magic.

```
SELECT REPLACE(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(foo, '/')), '/', '') conc
FROM (
    SELECT T_FOO.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FOO) R FROM T_FOO
)
START WITH r=1
CONNECT BY PRIOR r = r-1;
```

Answer (score 4):

The mysql way:

```
select group_concat(somecolumn separator '') from sometable
```

Comment: turned out not to be quite what i needed but i can tell this is gonna be really useful sometime

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that it's one column with multiple values, this approach works for MS SQL Server (I can't speak for other systems).

```
declare @result varchar(max)
set @result = ''

select @result = @result + RES
from (query goes here)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer you are looking for; I had a feeling the solution lay in the CONNECT BY operation, I just hadn't used the SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH pseudocolumn before (which displays the full path to the node in a tree, separating node names by a "/").  Assuming that your set of "foo" values before are multiple rows in a table, grouped by a column "myKey", e.g.:

```
myKey    foo
-------- ----------
group 1  apple
group 1  orange
group 1  pear
group 2  ape
group 2  bear
group 2  kitten
```

you can treat the data as if it were a tree schema, and pretend that the values of each group represent nodes going down a branch.  In that case, you'd do this:

```
  SELECT myKey
       , SUBSTR(MAX(REPLACE(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(foo, '/')
                           ,'/'
                           ,' '
                           )
                   )
               ,2
               ) FooConcat
    FROM ( SELECT MyKey
                , Foo
                , row_number() OVER (Partition by myKey order by myKey) NodeDepth
             FROM MyTable
         )
   START WITH NodeDepth = 1
 CONNECT BY PRIOR myKey = myKey
     AND PRIOR NodeDepth = NodeDepth -1
GROUP BY myKey
;
```

Of course, the order of the concatenated values would be random; if your table had another column ("bar") that you could use as an ordering field that was ascending and contiguous, you could dispense with the subquery (which only exists to put an imaginary depth to the tree) and use the table directly, replacing NodeDepth with bar.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Since version 8.4.0 CUBRID provides [90% compatibility](http://blog.cubrid.org/news/cubrid-8-4-0-has-arrived-w-x2-faster-database-engine/) with MySQL. Thus, it supports [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.cubrid.org/manual/840/en/GROUP_CONCAT%20Function) which has similar syntax as in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE t(i int);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (4),(2),(3),(6),(1),(5);

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(i*2+1 ORDER BY 1 SEPARATOR '') FROM t;

group_concat(i*2+1 order by 1 separator '')
======================
  '35791113'
```

Quite powerful, isn't it? And below is an [alternative solution](http://www.cubrid.org/concat_different_row_columns) supported natively in CUBRID.

```
SELECT MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(s_name, '')) AS conc_s_name
FROM (
     SELECT ROWNUM AS r, s_name FROM code
) AS res
START WITH r = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR r = r - 1;
```

It's so interesting that this way of concatenating different row column values in CUBRID is almost identical to Oracle's way as provided by @devio. In CUBRID it looks a little bit easier though.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on [How to concatenate all the records in a column returned by a query into one varchar string in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800843/how-to-concatenate-all-the-records-in-a-column-returned-by-a-query-into-one-varc?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
declare @s varchar(8000)
select @s = coalesce(@s + col, col) from tbl
```

This should solve

Comment: Instead of posting an answer which merely links to or copies another answer, please instead [flag the question](/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate if applicable.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying debatable? that question is TSQL. this one is just general SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating strings depends on the database you are using (you havnt mentioned what version in your question so here goes)...

In Oracle and DB2 you can use the `CONCAT` function... `CONCAT(string, string)`

SQL Server you can use the '+' operator... `string1 + string2 + string3`

In MySQL it is `CONCAT(string, string... n_string)`

Finally in PostgreSQL it is `TEXTCAT(string, string)`...

...I got this out of this little cool book I have sitting on my desk SQL Pocket Guide from O'Reilly... check it out!

**:)**

Comment: I know what you mean, you would do something like... Select @Text = @Text + RES, or Select @Text = CONCAT(@Text, RES) etc to concatenate the columns.

Comment: Does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

It might not be what you're looking for, but I've had good luck in the past with constructions like this:

```
SELECT      MAX(DECODE(fookey, 1, foo, NULL))
         || MAX(DECODE(fookey, 2, foo, NULL))
         || MAX(DECODE(fookey, 3, foo, NULL))
         || MAX(DECODE(fookey, 4, foo, NULL))
       , groupingvalue
    FROM mytable
GROUP BY groupingvalue;
```

It's platform independent, and it works well when you have a arbitrary, but limited number of values for foo, and they're based on some other key value.  For example, if you have a table of invoices, and you want to see all the line times from the invoice on a single row, concatenated, and you have an upper limit of 5 line items, it would look like this:

```
SELECT      MAX(DECODE(lineno, 1, foo, NULL))
         || ', '
         || MAX(DECODE(lineno, 2, foo, NULL))
         || ', '
         || MAX(DECODE(lineno, 3, foo, NULL))
         || ', '
         || MAX(DECODE(lineno, 4, foo, NULL))
         || ', '
         || MAX(DECODE(lineno, 5, foo, NULL))
       , invoiceid
    FROM lineitem
GROUP BY invoiceid;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
declare @ColumnNameList VARCHAR(MAX)


 SELECT @ColumnNameList  = COALESCE(@ColumnNameList +',' ,'') + ColumnName 
                     FROM 
                       <<table name>>

select @ColumnNameList
```

Answer (score 0):

ms sql
select string_agg(column_name,',') from table

Answer (score -3):

Select ([col1] +','+[col2]+','+ [col3]+','+[col4]) as [MyCol] From [Table]

Comment: the goal is to concatenate rows, not columns