# comma separated value in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concat all column values in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970481/concat-all-column-values-in-sql)

I have a table

```
ID | Name
1  | X
2  | y
3  | z
```

I have to show values in column Name  as comma separated i.e x,y,z.
One way I can do is looping the values of column "Name" and displaying as comma  separated.
Is there is a other way to do it.Please help.

Comment: Yes but as Klas says, the method for solving this has recently been changed for the better in Oracle 11.2

Comment: Can someone link to the canonical asking of this question?

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is a duplicate of several other questions, I'd like to give an answer, because the easiest way to do this has changed recently. Oracle has provided the very nifty LISTAGG function with the following syntax:

```
SELECT
   LISTAGG(name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)
FROM
   my_table;
```

LISTAGG is available since Oracle 11.2.

Comment: There is also an Oracle 9i kludge (the "hard" way?) with xmlagg: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_converting_rows_columns.htm