# Speed issues fetching Thousands of rows in a SQLCE database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-ce

Quick disclaimer first: I am a complete noob when it comes to databases. I know how to form an SQL query and... well,  that's pretty much it - I figured that'd be enough to start with. Performance optimizations would come later.

'Later' has arrived. I need your help.

I'm doing NLP-processing on news articles. The articles are taken from the Internet and stored in a database. Users give me an input period to analyze, I bring up all the articles in this period, analyze them and show them some graphs in return. I currently have a rather naive approach to this - I don't limit the number of articles returned. About 250 articles a day * 6 months is 45,000 records, a rather large number.

I'm experiencing mediocre fetch performance. I'm using C# + SQLCE (an easy DB to start with, with no set up cost). I tried indexing the database to no avail. I'm suspecting the problems comes from either

- asking for so much data in one single query.
- using SQLCE

Am I utterly crazy to try and fetch thousands of records all in 1 call ? Was SQLCE a stupid choice to make ? I basically need practical advice on this. Also, if you could point me to good alternatives to solve my problem that's even more awesome.

Your help is of great value to me - thanks in advance!

**EDIT** - Below is to command I use to get my articles:

```
using (SqlCeCommand com1 = new SqlCeCommand(mySqlRequestString, myConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCeResultSet res = com1.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable);
            if (res.HasRows)
            {
                //Use the get ordinal method so we don’t have to worry about remembering what order our SQL put the field names in.
                int ordGuid = res.GetOrdinal("Id"); int ordUrl = res.GetOrdinal("Url"); int ordPublicationDate = res.GetOrdinal("PublicationDate"); 
                int ordTitle = res.GetOrdinal("Title"); int ordContent = res.GetOrdinal("Content"); int ordSource = res.GetOrdinal("Source");
                int ordAuthor = res.GetOrdinal("Author"); int ordComputedKeywords = res.GetOrdinal("ComputedKeywords"); int ordComputedKeywordsDate = res.GetOrdinal("ComputedKeywordsDate"); 

                //Get all the Articles
                List<Article> articles = new List<Article>();
                if (res.ReadFirst())
                {
                    // Read the first record and get its data
                    res.ReadFirst();
                    Constants.Sources src = (Constants.Sources)Enum.Parse(typeof(Constants.Sources), res.GetString(ordSource));
                    string[] computedKeywords = res.IsDBNull(ordComputedKeywords)?new string[]{}: res.GetString(ordComputedKeywords).Split(',').ToArray();
                    DateTime computedKeywordsDate = res.IsDBNull(ordComputedKeywordsDate) ? new DateTime() : res.GetDateTime(ordComputedKeywordsDate);
                    articles.Add(new Article(res.GetGuid(ordGuid), new Uri(res.GetString(ordUrl)), res.GetDateTime(ordPublicationDate), res.GetString(ordTitle), res.GetString(ordContent), src, res.GetString(ordAuthor), computedKeywords, computedKeywordsDate));
                }
                // Read the remaining records
                while (res.Read())
                {
                    Constants.Sources src = (Constants.Sources)Enum.Parse(typeof(Constants.Sources), res.GetString(ordSource));
                    string[] computedKeywords = res.IsDBNull(ordComputedKeywords) ? new string[] { } : res.GetString(ordComputedKeywords).Split(',').ToArray();
                     DateTime computedKeywordsDate = res.IsDBNull(ordComputedKeywordsDate) ? new DateTime() : res.GetDateTime(ordComputedKeywordsDate);
                    articles.Add(new Article(res.GetGuid(ordGuid), new Uri(res.GetString(ordUrl)), res.GetDateTime(ordPublicationDate), res.GetString(ordTitle), res.GetString(ordContent), src, res.GetString(ordAuthor), computedKeywords, computedKeywordsDate));
                }
                return articles.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes in place? - some more concrete info would help a lot, like a CREATE TABLE script.

Comment: Real slow. Just made a test, took it ~15 seconds to get ~7500 records

Comment: What kind of app is this? Windows or web?

Comment: @ErikEJ: I didn't create my table programmatically. No CREATE TABLE, I used VS2010 directly. I've also tried indexing my databases, which didn't help much

Comment: Are you using DataReaders or DataAdapters/DataTables? The former has better perf and memory characteristics. If you could post the ADO.NET command (if it isn't too long), that might help suggest options.

Comment: I use `SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand(mySqlQuery, myConnectionString))`

Comment: Just updated my OP with the query code

Answer (score 0):

1. You should only fetch one page of results at a time.
2. SqlCE is great for testing or very low usage applications, but you should really consider [SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) or full blown SQL Server.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'pages of result' - see my OP. I analyze a chunk of data and return one graph. My problem comes from the size of that chunk - usually quite big. I'm not quite sure there's a way around fetching those thousands of records.

Comment: Can you parameterize your results or select aggregate values instead of every single row? No matter your data source, selecting 45,000 rows will not be fast.

Comment: Getting a concatenation of all strings in a given row might do it. Would that be faster to do ? Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970481/concat-all-column-values-in-sql

Comment: Can't really help without more detail, but everything you can do in the sql server, that reduces the number of rows, or columns will probably be of value.

Comment: I doubt concatenation will help. Since you're creating a graph, you must be doing some kind of aggregate calculations (sum, avg, max, etc) after building your article list. Try to do as much of that as you can in your sql query.

Comment: Hum... Solve an eigenproblem in an SQL query, anyone ? ;-)

Comment: @jrummell "Can you parameterize your results or select aggregate values instead of every single row? No matter your data source, selecting 45,000 rows will not be fast" --> how slow do you mean ? Tens of seconds slow ? Cos I'm ok with anything under say 5 seconds..

Comment: I was vague on purpose. =) It's all relative the to complexity of your query (number of rows, number of columns, where clause) and your schema (table size, column types, indexes, etc).