# Concatenate the values of a nested field on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Supose I have the following schema:

```
[
   {
        'name': 'id',
        'type': 'INTEGER' 
   }
   {
        'name': 'record',
        'type': 'RECORD',
        'fields': [
            {
                'name': 'repeated',
                'type': 'STRING',
                'mode': 'REPEATED'
            }
         ]
   }
]
```

And the following data:

```
+--------------------+
|id  |record.repeated|
+--------------------+
|1   |'a'            |
|    |'b'            |
|    |'c'            |
+--------------------+
|2   |'a'            |
|    |'c'            |
+--------------------+
|3   |'d'            |
+--------------------+
```

What I need is to create a query that returns this:

```
+--------------------+
|id  |record.repeated|
+--------------------+
|1   |'a,b,c'        |
+--------------------+
|2   |'a,c'          |
+--------------------+
|3   |'d'            |
+--------------------+
```

In other words, I need to query that allows me to concatenate the values of a nested field using a separator (in this case, comma). Something like the [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function of MySQL, but on BigQuery.

Related idea: [Concat all column values in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970481/concat-all-column-values-in-sql)

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's very simple

```
select group_concat(record.repeated) from table
```

an example from publicdata is

```
SELECT group_concat(payload.shas.encoded)
FROM [publicdata:samples.github_nested]
WHERE repository.url='https://github.com/dreamerslab/workspace'
```

Comment: Totally missed that on the documentation (I was looking at String functions). For the record: [Aggregate functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#aggfunctions).

Comment: how can I concat float numbers to a array? If i use group concat I have to convert the float to string and the conversions drop the precisions.

Comment: if you cast a value as far as i know you lose the precision

Comment: BigQuery says "Function not found: GROUP_CONCAT". This is a legacy function. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#group_concat

Answer (score 1):

For standard sql:

```sql
select id, string_agg(record.field)
from your_table, unnest(record)
```

or

```sql
select id, string_agg(record.field)
from your_table left join unnest(record)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_to_string()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_to_string)

```
WITH
  t AS (
  SELECT
    '1' AS a,
    '2' AS b)
SELECT
  ARRAY_TO_STRING([a, b], ',')
FROM
  t
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a LEFT JOIN with the REPEATED record and then use [STRING_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#string_agg) and DISTINCT, like this:

```
SELECT ol.RecordId, STRING_AGG(DISTINCT pmt.method," | ") AS PaymentType
FROM `my-dw.my-dataset.order_item` roi
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(order_line) ol
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(detail.payment) pmt
GROUP BY 1
LIMIT 100
```

The entire record can be repeated (ie, nested or node) or it is a "node in a node".  The example shows both.

[image]