# Pivot and concatenate values from column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have table with these columns:

```
ID | Name  | Value
------------------
 1 | Test1 | 0
 2 | Test2 | 1
 3 | Test3 | 0
 4 | Test4 | 0
 5 | Test5 | 1
```

And I want to have pivoted and concatenated value column as string

```
01001
```

Comment: In SQL only, or can you use PHP or something else for this?

Comment: If you just want it concatenated you could use `DECLARE @Txt1 VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Txt1=''
 
SELECT  @Txt1 = @Txt1 + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Value)
FROM    your_table

SELECT @Txt1`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27341271/1080354

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970481/concat-all-column-values-in-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code will give the expected result:

```
SELECT @Result = @Result + CAST(VALUE AS VARCHAR)
FROM #TmpTestingTable
```

Or you can use the `STUFF`:

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (   SELECT CAST(VALUE AS VARCHAR) 
        FROM #TmpTestingTable
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 1, 0, '')
```

For sample, I inserted the columns into the temporary table and execute the code.

```
CREATE TABLE #TmpTestingTable (ID INT, Name VARCHAR (20), Value INT)

INSERT INTO #TmpTestingTable (ID, Name, Value) VALUES
(1 , 'Test1' , 0),
(2 , 'Test2' , 1),
(3 , 'Test3' , 0),
(4 , 'Test4' , 0),
(5 , 'Test5' , 1)

DECLARE @Result AS VARCHAR (100) = '';

-- using variable approach
SELECT @Result = @Result + CAST(VALUE AS VARCHAR)
FROM #TmpTestingTable

SELECT @Result

-- using STUFF approach
SELECT STUFF(
    (   SELECT CAST(VALUE AS VARCHAR) 
        FROM #TmpTestingTable
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 1, 0, '')

DROP TABLE #TmpTestingTable
```

Comment: calling concatination the *STUFF approach* is really misleading. All your STUFF does is replacing the first character with empty string

Answer (score 3):

Use [FOR XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) to concatinate. It is important that you also include an ORDER BY. Otherwise you have no control of the order of the values and you risk an arbitrary order.

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT CAST([VALUE] AS CHAR(1)) 
   FROM yourtable
   ORDER BY ID
   FOR XML PATH ('')
  )
```

Comment: Clean, simple, love it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Value SEPARATOR '') FROM Table
```

**EDIT:**

Not working on SQL Server. Have a look at [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server) to try to make it work

Comment: Looks like mysql, not sql-server

Comment: I found http://groupconcat.codeplex.com but I don't want to use external software