# SQL manipulation in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns `LocationCity` and `LocationCountry`. I need to concatenate them into a single column.

What I have now is :

```
select 
    LocationCity, LocationCountry 
from 
    Location
```

This produces an output like:

```
 Hitchin,England    United Kingdom
```

But my desired output is :

```
Hitchin, England, UK
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: try searching first this is a very common problem

Comment: How do we know how to translate `United Kingdom` to `UK`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concat all column values in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970481/concat-all-column-values-in-sql)

Comment: simple question no need to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## String Concatenation

### For SQL 2012 or Above

For SQL Server 2012 or newer, you can use the `CONCAT` function

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  REPLACE(LocationCity, ',', ', ')
  , ', '
  , LocationCountry
)
FROM Location
```

### Under SQL 2012

For versions before SQL Server 2012, there is no `CONCAT` function, but you can use string concatenation:

```
SELECT (
  REPLACE(LocationCity, ',', ', ')
  + ', '
  + LocationCountry
)
FROM Location
```

If `LocationCity` is nullable use the following query

```
SELECT (
  ISNULL(
    REPLACE(LocationCity, ',', ', ') + ', '
    , ''
  )
  + LocationCountry
)
FROM Location
```

If `LocationCity` must act as null if empty use the following query

```
SELECT (
  ISNULL(
    NULLIF(
      REPLACE(LocationCity, ',', ', ')
      , ''
    ) + ', '
    , ''
  )
  + LocationCountry
)
FROM Location
```

## Transform LocationCountry to short form

This might require to add another table or another column (dirty way)
which contains the short form of your `LocationCountry` column.

Then you can concatenate it the same way as before.
If the data is contained in another table, you may have to put a `JOIN`

## References

[CONCAT Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql)
[String Concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql)
[Using JOINs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx)
[REPLACE Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/en-uk/library/ms186862.aspx)

Comment: i am getting this error: 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Try `LocationCity || ',' || LocationCountry` instead. (ANSI SQL version.)

Comment: What SQL version are you on @user8096071 ?

Comment: sql server 2008

Comment: what if LocationCity is null? and how to change country name to short form like UK instead of United kingdom

Comment: If LocationCity is nullable, you can add `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` function around it with the default value to replace. About Country Name, you will have to create your own column to get the replacement values from long names to short names.

Comment: i am using this query `select  isnull(NULLIF(LocationCity, '') + ',', '') +isnull(LocationCountry,'') as Location
 from Location`

Comment: actual output `Hitchin,England,United Kingdom` expected is i want space after every comma

Comment: Add a space then like in my answer

Comment: ur answer giving me `Hitchin,England, United Kingdom` without space after Hitchin